# C# - Access a one slice of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

Suppose a have a MxNx3 matrix

```
byte [,,] myMatrix= new byte[sizeRow, sizeCol, 3];
```

How do I access a single band of it (for read and write purposes)? Something like:

```
singleBand = myMatrix[:allRows: , :allCols: , :desiredBand:];
```

[image: On the left is what I have, of the right is what I want to access (for example.)]

On the left is what I have, of the right is what I want to access (for example).

Comment: You don't have a matrix, you have a byte array. Byte arrays dont know what bands or rows or columns are. 
You've asked for how to access a single band, but then shown an example which gets some variable representing a single band. Those are different things. You can easily access the band for read and write purposes simply by accessing the relevant members by index. Getting a variable representing a band would require the use of a matrix class with some awareness of bands.

Comment: Please provide an example. That's the purpose of the question :)

Comment: An example of what? Write a matrix class for you? Write `myMatrix[0,0,0] // accesses 0th element of top-left of matrix`?

Comment: How do I access a particular band in the example I've given (disregarding the fact that I called a matrix:)

Comment: I dont know what a band is but if I write `myMatrix[1,1,0] //access 0th element of one down and right from top-left of matrix` assuming it's a diagonal, can you extrapolate from there? Drawing a picture may help.

Comment: Try tuple class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int M=10;
int N=20;
var test = new byte[3][,] { new byte[N,M],new byte[N,M],new byte[N,M]};
var band1 = test[1]; //its green
band1[2, 2] = 99;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the type of `myMatrix`, then you can use the following code:

```
byte [,,] myMatrix= new byte[sizeRow, sizeCol, 3];
var singleBand = new byte[sizeRow, sizeCol];
var band = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < sizeCol; j++) {
        singleBand[i, j] = myMatrix[i, j, band];
    }
}
```

But if you can change it, then probably Zeromus' solution is better, since you can more easily manipulate with what you call the band.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop through your required array elements and extract the "band" that you need.

```
// Create a three-dimensional array.
int[, ,] threeDimensional = new int[3, 3, 3];

// Set the first "Band" to 9

threeDimensional[0,0,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[1,0,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[2,0,1] = 9;

threeDimensional[0,1,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[1,1,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[2,1,1] = 9;

threeDimensional[0,2,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[1,2,1] = 9;
threeDimensional[2,2,1] = 9;

// Loop over each dimension's length.
for (int i = 0; i < threeDimensional.GetLength(2); i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < threeDimensional.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < threeDimensional.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            Console.Write(threeDimensional[x, y, i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Your only option is to access each "cell" in the band one at a time and extract it to some other location. In my case i just put them out to the display.